# How to print zero for rows with no content?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I have two table of bank database. One is customer list and other is account list. When I left outer join customer to account I have records of customer which does not have anything. How can I print zero for them?

```
    SQL> CREATE TABLE Customer (
      2          BSB#            CHAR(6)         NOT NULL, /* Bank BSB number    */
      3          Customer#       NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL, /* Customer number    */
      4          Name            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Customer name      */
      5          DOB             Date,                     /* Date of birth      */
      6          Sex             CHAR,                     /* M-Male, F-Female   */
      7          Address         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL, /* Customer address   */
      8          Phone#          VARCHAR2(15),             /* Phone number       */
      9          CONSTRAINT Project_PK PRIMARY KEY(BSB#, Customer#),
     10          CONSTRAINT Project_FK FOREIGN KEY (BSB#) REFERENCES Bank(BSB#)
     11  );

SQL> CREATE TABLE Account (
  2          BSB#            CHAR(6)         NOT NULL, /* Bank BSB number    */
  3          Customer#       NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL, /* Customer number    */
  4          Account#        NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL, /* Account number     */
  5          Type            VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL, /* Account type       */
  6          Balance         NUMBER(10,2)    NOT NULL, /* Account balance    */
  7          CONSTRAINT WorksOn_PK PRIMARY KEY(BSB#, Account#),
  8          CONSTRAINT WorksOn_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BSB#, Customer#) REFERENCES Customer(BSB#, Customer#)
  9  );
```

Command:

```
select c.name, CUS.MYSUM
from customer c 
left outer join 
(
select customer#,sum(balance) MYSUM
from account 
group by customer# 
) CUS
on c.customer# = CUS.customer#;​
```

Outout:

```
NAME                                MYSUM
------------------------------ ----------
Ben                            -470211.09
Mike                           -470211.09
Jean                            -60028.03
Douglas                           1970.35
Josef                             1970.35
Duke                             54469.12
Alex                           -323631.76
Harry
Will
```

I want to print 0 in front of Harry and Will?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your first query line to

```
select c.name, COALESCE(CUS.MYSUM, 0)
```

`COALESCE` is a standard sql function that returns the value of the first expression among its arguments that does evaluate to NULL. if there is no such expression, it will return NULL instead.

a searched `CASE` expression provides similar functionality:

```
select c.name, CASE WHEN CUS.MYSUM IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE CUS.MYSUM END
```

the advantages are:

- the actual value used in the not-null case need not be the value of the inspected column
- you may test for arbitrary expressions

which come at the price of

- less readability
- performance impact ( often negligable, in complex queries result set projection [i.e. `select`-ing the columns] takes the least amount of processing time ).

ref: [mysql 5.0 doc on `COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) for this

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

```
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(1,0);
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(NULL,10);
    -> 10
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(1/0,10);
    -> 10
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(1/0,'yes');
    -> 'yes'
```

When handling single values, IFNULL should be preferred over COALESCE for readability if nothing else

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.name, CUS.MYSUM
from customer c 
left outer join 
(
select  customer#,CASE WHEN LEN(balance) <> 0 THEN sum(balance) ELSE 0 END    MYSUM
from account 
group by customer# 
) CUS
on c.customer# = CUS.customer#
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server, [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) can be used

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULL,0);
    -> 0

SELECT ISNULL(1,0);
    -> 1
```

But coalesce seems to be better:
http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull